# Applescript | Photos | SlideShow

Tags: applescript, slideshow, photos

How to I start a slideshow with applescript?

```
tell application "Photos"
start slideshow using folder "Monday"
end tell
```

This dosen't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Photos` dictionary:

> **folder** (noun), pl folders A folder. *A container that holds albums and
>   other folders, but not media items*
>
> **start slideshow** (verb) *Display an ad-hoc slide show from a list of media items, an album, a folder, or a moment (from Photos Suite)*

Although the description of the command `start slideshow` suggests that you can display a slideshow from a folder, it doesn't work.

You have to get the list of media items of an album in a folder.

```
tell application "Photos"
    set mediaItems to media items of album "myAlbum" of folder "Monday"
    start slideshow using mediaItems
end tell
```